# regex to exclude after first space

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php

$url = '/#123_abc" data-text="something-something"';
preg_match_all ('(/#.*)', $url, $result);


var_dump($result);
```

How can I get only `/#123_abc` ? I want to exclude `data-text="something-something"`

Comment: that pattern's invalid anyways. you don't have any delimiters.

Comment: OP is using `(` and `)` as delimiters it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negated character class as

```
/(^\/#[^"]+)/
```

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start
- `[^"]+` Negated character class, matches anything other that a `"`.

  `+` quantifies the pattern, matches one or more occurence.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/eD5qH9/1)

---

**Test**

```
$url = '/#123_abc" data-text="something-something"';
preg_match_all ('/(^\/#[^"]+)/', $url, $result);
var_dump($result[0]);
// => Outputs
// /#123_abc
```

---

P.S : You can prevent the escaping of `\` by using different pair of delimiters as

```
$url = '/#123_abc" data-text="something-something"';
preg_match_all ('~(^/#[^"]+)~', $url, $result);
var_dump($result[0]);
// => Outputs
// /#123_abc
```

Comment: And the delimiters are hiding?

Comment: what does the plus `+` do?

Comment: @Rizier123 There was some typo in that. Corrected now

Comment: @JenniferJackson The `+` is a quantifier. That is it repeates the previous pattern one or more times. In short the `+` ensures that anything other than `"` ( `[^"]`) occures for more than one time. Hope its clear for you

Answer (score 2):

`*` is a **greedy** operator which consumes as much as possible. Use the regex token `\w` instead.

```
$url = '/#123_abc" data-text="something-something"';
preg_match('~/#\w+~', $url, $result);
echo $result[0]; //=> "/#123_abc"
```

Comment: I understood my clumsiness looking at your suggestion. I still managed to find another approach :)

Comment: why use `~` instead of `/`?

Comment: Just user preference .

Comment: @hwnd it does the exact same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
/\#\S+?(?=")
```

Explanation:

- `/` - A literal forward slash
- `\#` - A literal hash symbol
- `\S+?` - 1 or more non-whitespace symbols
- `(?=")` - A positive look-ahead to check if we found a double quote.

[Sample code](https://ideone.com/o4qkKH):

```
$url = '/#123_abc" data-text="something-something"';
preg_match_all('#/\#\S+?(?=")#', $url, $result);
print_r($result[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /#123_abc
)
```

Comment: I am escaping `#` because I am using it as a delimiter here.